# CSS- HOVER affecting two divs

Tags: html, css, hover

I am a newbie to CSS. I have two divs, `div1` and `div2`.
The `div2` is inside `div1` and hovering over `div1`, the circle is transforming to blue back ground as per my requirement.

I have a letter "F" inside the `div2`. Now, hovering over the `div1` while the background color changes to blue, I want the "F" inside the `div2` to change to white.

How do I go about doing this?

Comment: You'll need to include your markup and the css at a minimum. It's difficult to tell what you're trying to achieve, not least of which because you mention something about a circle, which I have no idea what it has to do with the two divs mentioned.

Comment: Please use [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) to show a demo of your code.

Comment: It's not perfect, but try this - http://jsfiddle.net/aamh2djv/

Comment: I think the text needs to turn white as well, @MaryMelody, so I slightly modified your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/aamh2djv/1/

Comment: @MaryMelody thank you mary for the technical help.

Comment: @chipChocolate.py    Here is the snippet of my doubt http://jsfiddle.net/n9fngckj/

Comment: @KrishnaKrish TRY THIS DEMO - http://jsfiddle.net/n9fngckj/1/

Answer (score 4):

**As per your requirements** - **[TRY THIS DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/aamh2djv/5/)**

**HTML:**

```
<div id="div1"><div id="div2">F</div></div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#div1 {
    position:relative;
    background:red;
    width:400px;
    height:400px;
    line-height:200px;
    border-radius:200px;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:24px;
}
#div1:hover {
    background:blue;
}
#div2 {
    position: absolute;
    background:blue;
    top:100px;
    left:100px;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    background-color:lawngreen;
}
#div1:hover #div2 {
    color:white;
}
```

**[EDITED]**

As per your below comment: **[TRY THIS DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/n9fngckj/2/)**

> Here is the snippet of my doubt [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/n9fngckj/) – Krishna Krish

Comment: Thanks, it helped me for an issue I also had!